# Regcode/OG Issue - Need D7 Equivalent of og_all_groups_options()

Tags: forms, organic-groups, users

I'm trying to use the [Registration codes](http://drupal.org/project/regcode) module to automatically assign users to an organic group when they login with a registration code.

For Drupal 7, it appears that the Registration codes module is still using a Drupal 6 function (`og_all_groups_options()`) that is supposed to list all organic groups on a form.

I need to know the D7 equivalent of this function; I can't seem to find it.
Do you have a suggestion for how I could print out a multi-select option list of organic groups like `og_all_groups_options()` did?

Answer (score 1):

The closest one seems to be `og_get_all_group()` in og.module.